# How to break a single string into an array of strings?

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, string

I have a program in which I read from a string that's formatted to have a specific look.
I need the numbers which are separated by a comma (e.g. "A,B,D,R0,34,CDF"->"A","B","D","R0", "34", "CDF"). 
There are commas between letters that much is guaranteed
I have tried to do (note: "variables" is a 2D char array, newInput is a string which is a method argumend, k and j are declared and defined as 0)

```
for(int i=0; i<=newInput.Length; i++){
            while(Char.IsLetter(newInput[i])){
                variables[k,j]=(char)newInput[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            k=0;j++;

        }
```

with multi-dimensional character arrays.
Is there a way for this to be done with strings? Because char arrays conflict with many parts of the program where this method has already been implemented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 string MyString="A,B,D,R0,34,CDF";
 string[] Parts = MyString.Split(',');
```

And use them like:

```
Parts[0];//A
Parts[1];//B
Parts[2];//D
Parts[3];//R0
Parts[4];//34
Parts[5];//CDF
```

If you want to know more about Split function. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

Simple. Just use the [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var input = "A,B,D,R0,34,CDF";
var output = input.Split(','); // [ "A", "B", "D", "R0", "34", "CDF" ]
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to Split the string on line breaks use this

```
string str = "mouse\r\dog\r\cat\r\person\r\pig";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(str, "\r\n");
```

and if you want to split with chars , as input ,Split takes array of chars

```
char[] myChars = {':', ',', '.', '\u', ' ' };
string myString = "jack:tom kasra\unikoo car,pencil ball";
string[] myWords = myString.Split(myChars);
```